# Developing R package jpeg/png files under inst/doc are not appearing

Tags: r, devtools, cran

I am currently updating a package and am hitting a wall on this issue.
I haven't been able to find any documentation explaining why the png files under inst\doc are not appearing in the library folder when I run the following:

```
install(package_path)
```

using the devtools package where package_path is the path to the source folder for the package.

I do not have an .Rinstignore file and just in case I have made sure that my .Rbuildignore does not have any patterns matching png files.

Any help or direction towards documentation over this matter would be appreciated.

To help clarify:
Below (on the left) you can see the package within the library directory containing just the html files. This is the result of running the install() command on the library I am maintaining, "". On the right is the source directory containing the png files as well. These png  files are not being transferred over.

There is no additional code involved on my part.

[![![enter image description here][1]][1]

Now what is strange is that if I move the image files out of the inst directory, (So for example putting them in the root directory of the package), they do get copied over to the library.

Comment: So you want people to enumerate all the possible causes of this?

Comment: "Any help or direction towards documentation over this matter would be appreciated."


I am under the impression I am missing something obvious. Since I am using the installing functionality as a black box at this point as I was curious as to whether there was any documentation regarding images in the doc folder that I may have missed. 

But if you do know of any possible causes that would be helpful as I am out of ideas at this point. That is really all there is to it.

Comment: There's not enough detail here. If this is about a particular package it should be named. If the missing png files are known to exist _somewhere_ but R cannot find them then telling us why you think they should exist is needed. If this is a package you made then you should be able to strip it down to the bare essentials and post the code needed to create an example.

Comment: I guess that is my issue then. I do not know how to strip this down because I am black boxing the entire process using devtool's built in installation functionality for testing. Upon going through the devtools source code for the install function I could not find anything that should affect the copying of png files.

Comment: Are they in the built source tarball?

Comment: I am building the package directly from the unzipped source. I may be misunderstanding your question.

Comment: What's your workflow? i.e. summary what you did starting from get the source file. Did you work in RStudio and used a package project? Did you rebuild and reload the package? If you are going to do more stuff on packages, better read the great book by Hadley http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/ instead of black boxing, because then your problem will become black box for other people too, and you probably will run into wall from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

This is extremely old now, but I came across this thread because I had the same issue.

It seems to me that it is something to do with the name of the sub-directory in inst. I had the same problem with .png files in inst/doc/img which would not copy over on package build. But changing the file name to inst/markdown/img and everything copies fine.

Comment: same problem here .. any hope..
Also, a help page does not load all sub folders